# Does Black Mesa have a toggle scope option?

Tags: black-mesa, accessibility

I use a special mouse. With this mouse, it's not possible to left and right click simultaneously. This makes weapons with "hold right to scope/zoom, left click to fire" controls difficult to use.

Other games have a toggle scope option for accessibility; does Black Mesa have such an option?

Comment: If you're fine with using Autohotkey, [such option always exists](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/BioShock_Infinite#Change_from_toggle_to_hold_aim_down_sights) when not outright blocked by a game. Replace "BioShock Infinite" with the Black Mesa's window title and you should be set.